# What is the difference between regular and literal expressions in FINDSTR?

Tags: regex, cmd.exe, findstr

What is the difference between `/R` and `/C`?

```
FINDSTR [options] [/F:file] [/C:string] [/G:file]
        [/D:DirList] [/A:color] [/OFF[LINE]] [string(s)] [pathname(s)]

/C:string   Use string as a literal search string.
/R          Use string as a regular expression.

Q:\>dir
 Volume in drive Q is New Volume
 Volume Serial Number is 3AB5-2465

 Directory of Q:\

16-10-2014  09:34             3,072 keyspaceword.exe
16-10-2014  09:34             3,072 keyword.main1.xml
16-10-2014  09:34             3,072 keyword.main2.jpeg
16-10-2014  09:34             3,072 keyword.main3.exe
16-10-2014  09:34             3,072 keywordandmore.exe
16-10-2014  09:34             3,072 somethingkeyword.exe
24-09-2014  09:35    <SYMLINKD>     symlink1 [Q:\IIM\NOEXTNS]
               6 File(s)         18,432 bytes
               1 Dir(s)   7,180,222,464 bytes free

Q:\>dir | findstr /c:keyword
16-10-2014  09:34             3,072 keyword.main1.xml
16-10-2014  09:34             3,072 keyword.main2.jpeg
16-10-2014  09:34             3,072 keyword.main3.exe
16-10-2014  09:34             3,072 keywordandmore.exe
16-10-2014  09:34             3,072 somethingkeyword.exe

Q:\>dir | findstr /r /c:keyword
16-10-2014  09:34             3,072 keyword.main1.xml
16-10-2014  09:34             3,072 keyword.main2.jpeg
16-10-2014  09:34             3,072 keyword.main3.exe
16-10-2014  09:34             3,072 keywordandmore.exe
16-10-2014  09:34             3,072 somethingkeyword.exe
```

I thought I'd get only 3 files with /c:keyword (since keywordandmore.exe , somethingkeyword.exe) are not literal matches for keyword right?

Can someone explain with an example that highlights the difference between the two?
I've searched [here](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) but I'm still not entirely sure if my understanding is correct.

---

I think I found the difference but I still don't have any  explanation as to why this happens ? What about other meta-characters that I might need to escape ?

```
Q:\>dir | findstr /r /c:keyword.
16-10-2014  09:34             3,072 keyword.main1.xml
16-10-2014  09:34             3,072 keyword.main2.jpeg
16-10-2014  09:34             3,072 keyword.main3.exe
16-10-2014  09:34             3,072 keywordandmore.exe
16-10-2014  09:34             3,072 somethingkeyword.exe

Q:\>dir | findstr /c:keyword.
16-10-2014  09:34             3,072 keyword.main1.xml
16-10-2014  09:34             3,072 keyword.main2.jpeg
16-10-2014  09:34             3,072 keyword.main3.exe
16-10-2014  09:34             3,072 somethingkeyword.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regular expressions, `.` matches any character.

Hence, the search pattern `keyword.` matches `keyworda` in the file name `keywordandmore.exe` That's the reason for the disparity.

For more information about regular expressions, see [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).